# DNSimple with Heroku not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, dnsimple

I am having a problem with my DNS server that has just come up. I am following the OMR-One Month Rails tutorial. I don't quite understand how the whole DNS server thing works.

Only 1 out of 3 of my domains work, which is www.example.com. The naked domain (example.com) is not working and neither is example.heroku.com. Whenever I load these 2 addresses it DOES send me to heroku but I get the error message

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.

when I go to the terminal and type 'heroku domains' it shows that Heroku knows about all three domains.

How exactly do I configure DNSimple/Heroku so that all 3 addresses work, or at least the naked domain works.

Type    ----  Name      ----   Content

CNAME    ----   www.example.com     ----   example.herokuapp.com

ALIAS       ----  example.com       ----     www.example.com

TXT     ----  example.com       ----  ALIAS for www.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNS configuration is correct. The error you are reading "We're sorry, but something went wrong." is returned by Heroku (or you app), is not a DNS error.

You need to debug what's causing your app to crash.

You can inspect the Heroku logs by running

```
$ heroku logs --tail
```

That will show you the most recent log entries generated by your application.

Comment: Foolish me, you are correct. it didn't like this statement that I was using on my dropdown menu:
`<% if current_user.admin? %>`. But why would www.example.com still work and not the other 2 domains?